# How to detect arithmetic operation overflow in object c?

Tags: objective-c, exception, integer-arithmetic

In object c, how to detect an overflow like this

```
int a = INT_MAX;
int b = INT_MAX;
int result = a * b;
printf("%d x %d = %d\n",a, b, result);
```

And it shows

```
2147483647 x 2147483647 = 1
```

Can anybody tell me how to detect that kind of arithmetic operation error in object c?
Is it possible to use catch exceptions?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/199333/how-to-detect-integer-overflow-in-c-c.

Comment: Thanks a lot. That actually helps.